# Question about the solutions to quadratic congruence $x^2\equiv -1(\mbox{mod}\;p)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences, quadratic-residues

As is known to all, when $p\equiv 1(\mbox{mod}\; 4)$, there are 2 solutions to the congruence in the set $\{1,2,3,...p-1\}$:
$$x^2\equiv-1(\mbox{mod}\;p)$$
which to be exact are $\pm\frac{p-1}{2}!(\mbox{mod}\;p)$
My question is, are there infinitely many $p$ such that at least one of the $2$ solutions is a prime.

Comment: I think this is Artin's Conjecture, which you can google

Comment: @Joanpemo Google says Artin's Conjecture is about whether the primitive   root of $a$ module $p$ is $p-1$ or not, right?

Comment: As far as I know, it talks about non-quadratic residues or $\;-1=p-1\;$ *in general*, not only the latter. In fact, I think with $\;2\;$ was the original conjecture, but I am not sure.

Comment: This isn't related to Artin's conjecture.

Comment: I don't believe this has been proved yet, although it's probably within the power of current technology. Conjecturally, for example we believe that there are infinitely many primes $q$ for which $q^2+1=2p$ for some prime $p$; for these primes $p$, one of the solutions to $x^2\equiv-1\pmod p$ is the prime $q$.